# Spring boot basic authentication without UserDetailsService method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I want to implement a custom basic authentication on my aplication, but i dont want to use the UserDetailsService method...

```
@Override
public UserDTO loadUserByEmail(String email) {
    UserDTO user = userMapper.usertoUserDTO(userRepository.findByEmail(email));

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
    }

    return user;
}
```

Because i want to use my own service to retrieve the user.

After that it set the authorizator header on my response... Can some one help me please?

Can i make with basic authentication or i'll need to use jwt or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

`UserDetailsService` is just an interface and you should use your own implementation to load the user and return ( possibly your own ) implementation of `UserDetails` interface and then Spring will verify the password do the rest.

> After that it set the authorizator header on my response... Can some one help me please?

Even implementing your own `AuthenticationProvider` will not help here because you already don't have a `ServletRequest` object in context, but only `Authentication` details.

For this I believe you might need to use a `ServletFilter` instead.