# @PreAuthorize without username password and UserDetailsService interface

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, authority

So here is the scenario.

I have login API and it return jwt token to client, this API has annotation `@PermitAll`.

Then I have another API that is secured and can only be accessed after verifying jwt token. The request to secured API is sent in such a manner that `Authorization` parameter is added in the header with the value of jwt token and the request is passed to the secured API. Please note that `authorization type` for this API is `No Auth`. I wrote a class `JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter`in which i intercepted the request,  extracted the token, verified it, returned appropriate response, it all works well. But there is a problem, and the problem is that there is `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('RANDOM_PRIV_1')")` annotation at the top of the method in the controller class and it is not verified by the `JwtRequestFilter` and practically it shouldn't be since this is not its job to do that.

I know `list of GrantedAuthorities` are passed to the implementation of `UserDetailsService` and it gets verified by method `loadUserByUsername`. But I cannot use this interface's implementation, reason being, its implementation is called only when `authorization type` is `Basic Auth` and I am not using this type of Authentication.

So what I am looking for is an interface/class with I can verify `GrantedAuthorities`; the way it is verified by `UserDetailsService`.

If there is not such functionality then I have second working option of extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and in the `preHandle`, I verify token as well as verify grantedAuthorities associated with user and verify`(manually)` them against the PreAuthorize annotation present on the method. This is working for me, but still I am looking for much cleaner solution.

P.S: I went through this link as well but didn't find any useful information. 
[Spring boot basic authentication without UserDetailsService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082401/spring-boot-basic-authentication-without-userdetailsservice-method).

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use JWTs to authenticate requests, then you can use Spring Security's built-in support for it.

You'll still need to create the JWT yourself, but for processing the JWT and turning it into Granted Authorities, you can do:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests(...
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .jwt(jwt -> {})
    );
```

This tells Spring Security to stand up a filter (`BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter`) that extracts the token and processes it, probably a lot like your `JwtRequestFilter`.

Since you are creating the JWT locally (instead of using an Authorization Server, for example), you'll need to tell Spring Security how to verify the token. This is usually done with a symmetric key:

```java
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(...).build();
}
```

And finally, to your question about granted authorities. Assuming, for example, that the authority you mentioned (`RANDOM_PRIV_1`) is listed as a scope in your JWT, you can construct a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` bean:

```java
JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
        Collection<String> scopes = jwt.getClaim("scope");
        return scopes.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    });
    return converter;
}
```

And then add that to the DSL:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests(...
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .jwt(jwt -> jwt
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())
        )
    );
```

Then, when a JWT is presented in the request, Spring Security will process it, extract authorities, and verify that they match the one using the `@PreAuthorize` annotation.